# Compiler complains about wrong number of template arguments even if its correct in a boost library file

Tags: c++, templates, boost, compiler-errors

There is a file in the boost library called has_new_operator.hpp. I am getting the following error when i complile the file using GCC 4.3.1

> type_traits/has_new_operator.hpp:45: error: wrong number of template
>   arguments (1, should be 2) type_traits/has_new_operator.hpp:24: error:
>   provided for 'template struct boost::detail::test'

as per line 24 it expects 2 arguments and that is what is been passed in line 42. Also if you observe line 31, the same has been done but the compiler does not complain about it.

```
21: namespace boost {
22: namespace detail {
23: template <class U, U x> 
24:    struct test;
25:
26: template <typename T>
27: struct has_new_operator_impl {
28:    template<class U>
29:    static type_traits::yes_type check_sig1(
30:        U*, 
31:        test<
32:        void *(*)(std::size_t),
33:            &U::operator new
34:        >* = NULL
35:    );
36:    template<class U>
37:    static type_traits::no_type check_sig1(...);

39:    template<class U>
40:    static type_traits::yes_type check_sig2(
41:        U*, 
42:        test<
43:        void *(*)(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&),
44:            &U::operator new
45:        >* = NULL
    );
```

Comment: Please give more context, [it gives me an error on both lines](http://ideone.com/VTxeA).

Comment: Gcc 4.3.1 isn't exactly the latest release. Perhaps this only works for a positive result but fails when the operator is missing?

Comment: iammilind pointed out that it could be because of std::size_t not being visible. It turned out that std::nothrow_t was not visible. In your code, both std::size_t and std::nothrow_t are not visible to the program.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `std::size_t` is not visible to your current code. You can try `#include<iostream>` before this code.

[Simulating your error](http://www.ideone.com/wEry6).

[Fixing your error](http://www.ideone.com/1CIfr).

Comment: `#include<cstddef>` would do the job without including all of iostream

Comment: The problem is with std::nothrow_t (line:43) being not visible. I included a file which contained nothrow_t in the std namespace and it worked fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with std::nothrow_t (line:43) being not visible. I included a file which contained nothrow_t in the std namespace and it worked fine. Thanks for your responses.